# Is it possible to have model inside model Room DB

Tags: android, android-sqlite, dao, android-room, android-database

Is it possible to have a model inside another model with Room in android. What I exactly want to do is:

**UserModel**

```
Public class User{

 String name, email, phone;
 //getter and setters

}
```

And a Passenger model

**PassengerModel**

```
Public class User{

 UserModel model;
 String seatNo;

 //getter and setters

}
```

If not provided in room,then how can I achieve this kind of structure in android

Comment: use a `@ForeignKey`? https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one nested object, you have to use @Embedded to include reference to UserModel class:

```
@Entity
Public class UserModel {

 String name, email, phone;

 //getter and setters

}
```

And a Passenger model :

```
@Entity
Public class PassengerModel {

  @Embedded
  UserModel model;

  String seatNo;

 //getter and setters
}
```

Thanks.